# Options for multiple answer

Tags: feature-request

Some time multiple users gave same answer in that case it's became difficult for question owner to select the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question asker has several reasonable options:

- choose neither  (though this can hurt your accept rate)
- choose the one that posted first  (perfectly reasonable and what I usually do)
- wait for one answerer to outdo the other via edits, or prod for more detail and the one that provides better overall detail gets awarded the accept  (better overall for the site, but not always applicable)

Comment: @Danie:I agree with you.But the problem comes when the users are like  John Skeet,Marc Gravell,Eric Lippert.They all are masterpiece

Comment: Then bite the bullet and choose the first or second option :)  In fact, in those cases, it's even less important to the actual answerers whose answer gets accepted because they have rep to spare already.

Comment: @Daniel:thanks for encouraging comments :)

Comment: somebody have voted down me :)

Comment: Yeah I saw that and gave it an upvote to balance it out (and actually net in your favor!)

Comment: @santosh a down vote on meta just means "disagree" with the request, not that the question is poor.   Someone must not agree with your suggestion, don't take it personally.